# Real-time ping result using ajax

Tags: java, real-time, ping

I'm trying to create a web application which can display the results of a ping command real-time. I'm using JSP in the backend. I'm actually getting the result correctly. But the problem is, the result is not displayed in real-time. The application processes the ping command and dumps the result all at once. What I  need is that, the application has to display the result line after line as and when a line of result is obtained.

Here is my code

```
String ip = request.getParameter("ipaddress");

String pingCmd = "ping -c 3 " + ip;

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process p = runtime.exec(pingCmd);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    out.println(inputLine + "<br />");
}
in.close();
```

What is the change I need to make in this code.

Regards

Sunil Kumar B M

Comment: Why are ajax, javascript, and jsp tagged?

Comment: use 1 ping instead and loop it three times . Isn't there some ping class you can use ? also, this isn't ajax

Comment: @Walkerneo: The code I've mentioned above is a java servlet code. I'll use ajax call to invoke this code

Comment: @sjums : If I use one ping and loop it n times, it shows some prologue data before the result and statistics after that. Is there any other way??

Comment: And then It's hosted, viewed in a browser which parse it,and execute the javascript before we get to your question, so you better add Apache,Chrome,webkit,V8, xmlhttprequest and TCP to the tags

Comment: Check the ping command args. -a might be useful

Comment: @sjums: what is the use of -a arg in ping? the man page says it 'audible ping'

Comment: Ohhh. I thought you were on Windows.. nvm then

Comment: @sjums: what is the use of -a option on windows

Comment: As I read it it'll only print the ping reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a comet servlet. For tomcat 6: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html

Comment: comet takes too much of resources in terms of processing, is there any other alternative??